# How to find the $l$ in $-\epsilon + 1 < l < \epsilon + 1$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Suppose we have:

$$ \epsilon > 0 $$

and

$$ -\epsilon + 1 < l < \epsilon +1 $$

I think I have enough information to show that $l=1$ but I don't know how to formally show that this is true.

Please help.

Comment: From $l<\epsilon+1$ follows $l\leq \epsilon$. Can you proof this? $l>1-\epsilon$ implies analogously $l\geq 1$. Hence $l=1$. You can show the first part for example  by contradiction assuming that $l>1$. Probably you still need that the estimate holds for every $\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any **fixed choice** of $\epsilon>0$, the real number
$$l=1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
satisfies
$$1-\epsilon<l<1+\epsilon$$
but $l\neq 1$. *However*, if for a **fixed choice** of real number $l$, it is the case that 
$$1-\epsilon<l<1+\epsilon$$
for *every* $\epsilon>0$, then you can conclude that $l=1$. You can do this as follows: by [the trichotomy property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_%28mathematics%29) of the real numbers, if we assume for the sake of contradiction that $l\neq 1$, then it must be the case that either $l>1$ or $l<1$.

If $l>1$, then when $\epsilon=\frac{l-1}{2}$, it is not true that
$$l<1+\epsilon,$$
which is a contradiction. If $l<1$, then when $\epsilon=\frac{1-l}{2}$, it is not true that
$$1-\epsilon<l,$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore our assumption must have been false, so $l=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I please know what made you decide to set $\epsilon$ to $\frac{l-1}{2}$?